# What is the command that lists all the peripheral devices connected to the computer in xubuntu?

Tags: devices

I need to know what is the command that lists all the pheripheral devices connected to the computer, I already used this command but I really don't remember its name.

Comment: I think you're looking for `lshw`.

Answer (score 4):

`lsblk` will show all of the drives and mountpoints, including USB.

`lspci` will show hardware, including peripherals.

`dmesg` will show latest kernel messages, which includes peripheral connects/disconnects.

Comment: And `lsusb` will list all USB devices, `lspnp` all legacy PnP devices, `lsscsi` all SCSI devices, `lscpu` all CPUs, ...